# Find edges of multiplicity larger than 2 in a NetworkX MultiGraph

Tags: python, networkx

I have a `MultiGraph` which can have multiple edges between any two nodes:

```
g = MultiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4,5,6])
g.add_edges_from([(1,2), (2,1), (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (6,5), (3,5), (3, 5), (3, 5), (3, 5)])
```

How can I find all edges with multiplicity larger than 2 in this graph? I can do something like this:

```
for s in itertools.combinations(g.nodes(), 2):
    e = g[s[0]].get(s[1], {})
    if len(e) > 2:
        print(s[0], s[1])
```

but it is too inefficient, so I'm looking for a better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for u in G.nodes():
    for neighbor in G.neighbors(u):
        if G.number_of_edges(u,neighbor)>2:
            print (u,neighbor)
```

Note - each such edge will be printed twice.

Comment: This has a running time of O(n^2) with n is the number of nodes. I am looking for something that's more efficient.

Comment: This has a running time of `O(E)` where `E` is the number of edges (which could possibly be O(N^2) if it's a dense graph).  How do you expect to be more efficient than checking each edge?  It's much better than what you've written which is O(N^2) even when the number of edges is small.

Answer (score 0):

```
[x for x in tmp.edges if tmp.number_of_edges(x[0], x[1]) > 1]
```